# Visual Studio 2008 doesn't appear X64 option for win 7 64 bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, sdk, 64-bit

I install visual studio 2008 express on win 7 64 bit and I also install Windows Software Development Kit (SDK).

I try to transform a DLL(c++ source code) from 32 to 64 bit but the X64 option doesn't appear in visual studio 2008.

I use command "vcvarsall amd64" in "Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt" but the error message "The specified configuration type is missing. The tools for the configuration might not be installed" is displayed.

How to fix this problem? What am I missing?

Comment: Seems like you have installed the default configuration. You to install Visual Studio using advanced options and select desired package (if it exists in express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 express don't support x64 build from box.

See: https://github.com/enGits/engrid/wiki/Configure-Microsoft-Visual-Studio-2008-Express-to-also-build-for-Windows-x64